# Simple way to call 'cat' from c++?

Tags: c++, linux, cat

I am writing some C++ code and I need to pre-allocate an array based on the contents of a file. I can definitely read the the file and parse the strings a certain way, but it's must easier to find the proper number from the following Linux one-liner:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep 'Freqs ---' | sed 's/Freqs ---//g' | wc -w
```

What is the best way to use this single one liner on the file from within the C++ code?

Comment: you can use system calls: fork(), pipe() and execlp(). But I think it can be done easier.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Comment: As a parameter to the program, ie. argv[1]?

Comment: Why do you think forking these four processes would be easier than using your chosen language to extract the number from the file?

Comment: It's faster to code ;)

Comment: Are you preallocating because you think realloc is slow? If so, forking and executing four processes instead is silly. By the way, UUOC.

Comment: @kometen I don't want the end user to have to worry about this so I don't want it passed as a parameter

Comment: @rici - This isn't for speed of execution but speed of getting the idea off the ground. I write a 'get_freqs' function and `popen` right now, but as the software starts to take shape and I have proven it works, I can make it more efficient later. For that matter, this is done one time in a code which will take hours to run, so that `ms` of time is negligible in the big scheme of things.

Comment: @Laurbert515: OK, fair enough. Since this is C++, you *could* just use a std::vector, which would make on-demand resizing trivial. Usually people avoid that because of fear of malloc, which leads to all sorts of uglinesses. Hence my reaction. Anyway, you don't need `cat` or `grep`. Or even wc, really: `awk 'sub(/Freqs ---/,""){c+=NF}END{print c}' myfile.txt` should do it all.

Comment: Very true. In fact, I do use vector. I was slightly incorrect in stating that I needed it for allocation. It is used in loops and some stopping conditions as well as a simple (resize) for my vector. I realized a flaw in my logic three years ago and wanted a quick and dirty way to test it out before optimizing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `popen` from `<stdio.h>`:

```
FILE *fp;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

fp = popen("cat myfile.txt | grep 'Freqs ---' | sed 's/Freqs ---//g' | wc -w", "r");
if (fp != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s", buffer);
    pclose(fp);
}
```

The return value from `popen` is a standard I/O stream, just like one returned by `fopen`. However, you should use `pclose` instead of `fclose` to close the stream.

Comment: I think calling your buffer `path` is rather confusing. The output of `wc -w` is a number.

Comment: That's true, I copy pasted my code from place where the output lines were paths.

Comment: So, I renamed buffer to `buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `system()` can be a dangerous business (in a hostile environment).
Using `popen()` is not much better.
It really is better to learn how to do this sort of thing right in your program:

This will get the size of a file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
 ...
struct stat st;
 ...
size_t bytes = 0;

if (stat("myfile.txt", &sb) == -1) { /* an error, do something */ }
else bytes = st.st_size;
```

However to do what your one liner does will require reading the file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t  bytes = 0;
char    line[256];
FILE *  fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
char *  p;
char *  freqs;
int     n;

if (fp == NULL) { /* an error, do something */ }
else while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    for (n = 0, p = line; (p = strstr(p, "Freqs ---")) != NULL; n++) {
        p += 9;                                    /* skip past found one */
    }
    if (n != 0) bytes += strlen(line) - (n * 9);   /* line len less n "Freqs ---" */
}
if (fp) fclose(fp);
```

Because of the `g` in your `sed` command, I assumed `Freqs ---` might occur more than once per line.  If it never occurs more than once, the code could be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `system` function from the standard library ("inherited" from C). Something like:

```
system("cat myfile.txt | grep 'Freqs ---' | sed 's/Freqs ---//g' | wc -w");
```

The documentation for this function is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

To get the result - output from `wc`, redirect it to a file and then open the file and `strtod` its contents.

Comment: the problem with system is getter the result of the wc command. the ret val is just an int flag. an easy workworund would be to include > tmp_fil in the wc and then read the file the "usual" way. but i guess popen, as suggested in other answers, may be more convenient

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `popen()` but such approaches are not all that portable.

Here is 21 year old (!!) snippet I had in a `misc/C/` subdirectory:

```
/* edd 01.11.95 write pipe to "wc" command */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *pipe;

  pipe = popen("wc", "w");
  fprintf(pipe, "w\n");
  fprintf(pipe, "wc\n");
  pclose(pipe);
  return 0;
}
```

You can also read from a pipe (just like you can from a file) and would then use, say, `fscanf()` to read your answer.