# How to read .inp file in c++?

Tags: c++, dataset

I have a dataset, a ".inp" format file, and I need to read this file in c++. However, the *fopen() fread()* method seemed to fail and read the wrong data(e.g. the first integer should be 262144, the fread yields an integer much larger than this nevertheless).

To be more specific, my ".inp" file contains a few *integers* and *float points*, how can I read them successfully in c++?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAV4I.png)
This is the screenshot of the "*.inp" file from Notepad++. Basically this is a text file.

Comment: Do you know the structure of the file? Is it perhaps written in big endian format and not little endian? That could explain the difference in values.

Comment: I don't know what an ".inp" format file is. Can you share the specification please?

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of the "*.inp" file, could you guys help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by coping the data into a txt. However, I am still not aware how to read "*.inp"

Answer (score 0):

I found some info about INP file extension. It seems like there are multiple variances of it, each meant to be used for different purpose. Where is your file coming from? As for soultion, if you can't open the file using fopen/fstream normally, you could treat it as binary and read each value in the way you specify. Other than that, I could think of calling system functions to get file contents (like cat in linux for example), then if there are some random characters, you could parse your string to ommit them.

Here is example of how to call cat in C++:
[Simple way to call 'cat' from c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970182/simple-way-to-call-cat-from-c)